Using TypeGuard on class method
Problem
I am trying to get something as follows to work:
from abc import ABC

class Foo(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self) -> str | None: ...

    def has_value(self) -> TypeGuard[FooWithValue]:
        return self.value is not None

class FooWithValue(Foo, ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self) -> str: ... 

With the desired use case to be able to have code like:
foo = SomeFoo()
print(f"foo has value: {foo.value}") if foo.has_value() else print("foo has no value")

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the TypeGuard does not seem compatible with class methods.
EDIT: To be specific, TypeGuard applies to the 2nd argument of a class method. See for example PEP 742:

If a type narrowing function is implemented as an instance method or class method, the first positional argument maps to the second parameter (after self or cls).

Is there a way of getting the class method to work with the type guard, or to achieve the same effective result?
Workaround
As a workaround, defining a standalone function does work, but I feel it isn't quite as nice:
def foo_has_value(foo: Foo) -> TypeGuard[FooWithValue]:
    return isinstance(foo, FooWithValue) or foo.value is not None

I would prefer to avoid this, if possible.

"I feel it isn't quite as nice" On the contrary, it's much nicer, because it's obvious what type you are checking for. The type of x in x.has_value() isn't in question: it's Foo, regardless of the value of one of its attributes (which is at best implied by the name of the method, not any argument to the function).

Also, "if x has type FooWithValue, then x.value has type str" is true; the converse isn't necessarily true.

I think your comments are a bit off-topic @chepner. You say "The type of x in x.has_value() isn't in question: it's Foo, regardless" is true, but things can have more than one type (or in a Pythonic sense, it is possible that separate isinstance(x, ...) be simultaneously true). As an analogy, even integers are a subset of all integers, and it might just be nice to know whether my integer is an even integer using a method call.
As for your second comment, I never claimed the converse is true. I did intentionally use "if" instead of "if and only if".

When used to mark the return type of an instance or class method, TypeGuard/TypeIs always applies to the second parameter (right after self/cls). This is non-configurable.
Prefer checking .value directly:
value = foo.value                     # value: str | None

if value is not None:
    print(f"foo has value: {value}")  # value: str
else:
    print("foo has no value")         # value: None

Alternatively:
(playgrounds: Mypy, Pyright)
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def has_value(instance: Foo) -> TypeGuard[FooWithValue]:
        return instance.value is not None

foo: Foo = ...

if Foo.has_value(foo):
    reveal_type(foo)        # FooWithValue
    reveal_type(foo.value)  # str
else:
    reveal_type(foo)        # Foo
    reveal_type(foo.value)  # str | None


Perhaps the question was not clear, but I'm asking if it is possible to get a class method to achieve the same outcome as a TypeGuard, specifically to avoid code like what you have.
Also, your comment about EAFP/LBYL is irrelevant to the question.

@JP-Ellis As far as I'm aware, no, it isn't possible. Comment revised.
